# Sumbit user name and surname and go to the next page

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out how to connect function that will save name and surname in local storage and go to the other page. If you could point out the problem I would be very grateful :)

```
index.html
<form id="from" action="" method="post">
    <div>
        <pre> <label for="name">Име</label></pre>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text"  required>
        <br>
        <pre><label for="surname"> Презиме </label></pre>
        <input id="surname" surname="surname" type="text"  required>
        <br><br>
    </div>
    <a href="quiz.html"><button onclick="sumbit()"> Започни тест </button> </a> 
</form>



script.js
let infs = [];
    const addInf= (ev)=>{
        ev.preventDefault();  //to stop the form submitting
        let inf = {
            id: Date.now(),
            name: document.getElementById('name').value,
            surname: document.getElementById('surname').value
        }
        infs.push(inf);
        document.forms[0].reset(); // to clear the form for the next entries

        //saving to LS
        localStorage.setItem('MyInfList', JSON.stringify(infs) );
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addInf);
    });
```

Comment: it should store data in the local storage

Comment: With this code it is storing, I can not figure out how to redirect to the other HTML page with the same button :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, use window.location for redirecting to another page, it has same functionality as href.

```
<form id="from" action="" method="post">
  <div>
    <pre> <label for="name">Име</label></pre>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required>
    <br>
    <pre><label for="surname"> Презиме </label></pre>
    <input id="surname" surname="surname" type="text" required>
    <br><br>
  </div>
  <a><button id="btn"> Започни тест </button> </a>
</form>


<script>
  let infs = [];
  const addInf = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault(); //to stop the form submitting
    let inf = {
      id: Date.now(),
      name: document.getElementById('name').value,
      surname: document.getElementById('surname').value
    }
    infs.push(inf);
    //saving to LS
    localStorage.setItem('MyInfList', JSON.stringify(infs));
    document.forms[0].reset(); // to clear the form for the next entries
    window.location = "quiz.html"
  }
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addInf);
  });
</script>
```